# Change model fields at runtime

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have some model:

```
from salesforce.models import SalesforceModel

class Task(SalesforceModel):
    card = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    who = models.ForeignKey(Lead) # here may be Lead or Contact model ID
```

and some func to update data:

```
def set_contact(contact):
    ...
    # Trying to change
    Task.who = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    # Or so:
    Task._meta.get_field('who').to = Contact
    task = Task.objects.get(...)
    task.who = contact
```

ofcourse django doesn’t allow to change value.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "Contact: Some Contact": "Task.who" must bea "Lead" instance.
```

Comment: Are you sure this would work? If you have a Task with a 'who' of, say, 341, how do you know whether to look for Contact number 341 or Lead number 341?

Comment: Yes, each record has unique id for whole DB

Answer (score 0):

Django builds it's models at runtime, and doesn't allow you to alter them after that.

Have you looked into [django_polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic):

```
from polymorphic import PolymorphicModel

class ContactBase(PolymorphicModel):
    ...

class Contact(ContactBase):
    ...

class Lead(ContactBase):
    ...

class Task(models.Model):
    card = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    who = models.ForeignKey(ContactBase)
```

Or perhaps [Django's generic foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Task(models.Model):
    card = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Either of these solutions would allow you to have multiple models attached to Task, but I find the Polymorphic route cleaner to work with.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear, these models have 'SalesforceModel' not 'models.Model', so "metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases". Also I can't add any fields for GenericForeignKey.

Comment: I tried to combine PolymorphicModelBase and SalesforceModelBase, it makes query to ContactBase table which isn't